# How do you sort an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Firstly, I am a beginner to java and programming in general so some of the solutions I've seen to this question aren't understandable to me.

However... basically, I have an array of temperatures, given by the arguments.
 i.e. temp[0] = 30, temp[1] = 31, temp[2] = 31, temp[3] = 30

The catch is I need to sort these temperatures into numerical order so that I can find the median temperature. However, I am unsure how to do this.

Any ideas? I was thinking along the lines of creating a second array with with the temperatures in order as the index increase. Then finding the middle value of the middle index by something along the lines of orderedTemps[(args.length - 1) / 2] (using an if statement to determine between an even and odd number of args as the median will differ).

However, I'm unsure about how to go about to sorting process and then creating a second array from sorting it... any tips?

Comment: You can use `Arrays.sort(yourArray)` to simplify, but I would take a look at [Sorting Algorithms](http://www.cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/java/sort/) to learn how they work.

Comment: There are several ways in which you can sort arrays, and it's up to you to choose one and try to implement it - [Sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: @BlackSlash, Does "Arrays.sort(yourArray)" create a new array, based on the sorted values from the original?

Or does it simply switch the index numbers of the orignal array in so that array[0] is the lowest value and array[x] is the highest?

Comment: @Wolff It edits the array passed as parameter, it doesn't create a new array

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`Median`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Median.html) from `org.apache.commons` package.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [java.util.Arrays sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5b%5d%29) method